# warning C5240: 'nodiscard': attribute is ignored in this syntactic position

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, warnings, nodiscard

Recently version 16.9.5 of Visual Studio 2019 has been released. It apparently introduced new warning:

```
[[nodiscard]] __declspec(dllexport) bool foo(); //ok
__declspec(dllexport) [[nodiscard]] bool bar(); // warning C5240: 'nodiscard': attribute is ignored in this syntactic position
```

Actually I thought that both nodiscard and dllexport are attributes that can appear in any order, or it is not?

Comment: One is standard, the other is implementation-specific. There's not really a "correct" behavior here in terms of any specification. As a QoI issue, I'd agree this is surprising/vexing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got this warning today too, so decided to look into it. This requires looking a bit at the standard, and putting different sections together.

According to [`[dcl.fct.def.general]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.general), a function is defined as:

```
function-definition:
   attribute-specifier-seq_opt decl-specifier-seq_opt declarator virt-specifier-seq_opt function-body
```

The reason this is important, is that it specifies that the optional `decl-specifier-seq` comes *after* the `attribute-specifier-seq` (which includes `[[nodiscard]]`).

Now, according to [`[dcl.spec.general]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.general#nt:decl-specifier-seq), a `decl-specifier-seq` is defined as:

```
decl-specifier-seq:
   decl-specifier attribute-specifier-seq_opt
   decl-specifier decl-specifier-seq
```

According to Microsoft's documentation of [`__declspec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/declspec?view=msvc-160), it is defined as a `decl-specifier`; thus, the `__declspec(dllexport)` must come after the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute.

Note:

> The optional attribute-specifier-seq in a decl-specifier-seq appertains to the type determined by the preceding
> decl-specifiers

Thus, the `[[nodiscard]]` *after* the `__declspec(dllexport)` applies only to the `__declspec(dllexport)`